Defined $A=\{x\in\mathbb R : f(x)>0\}$, is it always possible to write $A=A_1\cup A_2$ and $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$ in this way?
Let $f, g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be Lebesgue integrable functions and let $A=\{x\in\mathbb R : f(x)>0\}$.
I am wondering if it is always possible define $A_1=\{x\in A : f(x)\ge g(x)\}$, $A_2=\{x\in A : f(x)< g(x)\}$ and if they satisfy
$$A=A_1\cup A_2, \qquad A_1\cap A_2 =\emptyset.$$
Is that possible?
Also, if it is true, am I allowed to write
$$\int_A f(x) g(x) dx = \int_{A_1} f(x) g(x) dx + \int_{A_2} f(x) g(x) dx?$$
Also: for any $x\in A_2$, is it possible to write $g(x) = f(x) + a$, with $a\in\mathbb R^+$? Does $a$ depend on $x$?
I apologize if this is a dumb question. I am solving an exercise and I would like to use this argument at some point.

Of course you can write $A$ like that, not sure what makes you think otherwise. I'll leave it to you to check the two equalities of sets, I'm sure you can do that if you already learn measure theory.
As for the integrals equality, this is also true. Note that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are measurable sets, and the indicator function satisfies $\chi_A=\chi_{A_1}+\chi_{A_2}$ (why?), and so on $A$:
$fg=fg\cdot\chi_A=fg\cdot\chi_{A_1}+fg\cdot\chi_{A_2}.$
Now use the linearity of integral.

Mark, thank you for the answer. I was about to edit the question to add one more question: for any $x\in A_2$, is it possible to write $g(x) = f(x) + a$, with $a\in\mathbb R^+$? Does $a$ depend on $x$?

@Physicsuser Well, if $g(x)>f(x)$ then $a:=g(x)-f(x)$ is a positive real number, right? And in most cases it of course depends on $x$.

There is any way to "remove" the dependence on $x$? I mean, maybe taking $\alpha=\max_{x\in A_2} (g(x)-f(x))$ so that for any $x\in A_2$ it is $g(x)\le f(x)+\alpha$?

..the maximum could not exist, I meant the supremum over the points $x\in A_2$.

@Physicsuser But the maximum will not make it equality for every $x$. There are way too many Lebesgue integrable functions. For example, if $f,g$ are such functions such that $g(x)>f(x)$ always holds and $g-f$ is not a constant, there will surely be dependence on $x$.

Will it make $g(x)\le f(x) +\alpha$ for any $x\in A_2$?

@Physicsuser If this supremum is finite then of course.

Mark, I am sorry to take the discussion to long. For example, if $A_2$ has finite measure, then the supremum is finite, isn't it?

@Physicsuser Not necessary. The set $(0,1)$ has finite measure. Take $f=0, g=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.
